# PHP script keeps returning number values as strings

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have PHP script that makes an connection to a mySQL database that makes a query and returns data that is then looped through and added to an array. Here is my php script:

```
<?php
// Database credentials
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'demo';
$dbPassword = 'demo';
$dbName = 'syndicationdashboard';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Create connection and select db
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// Get data from database
$sql = "select Priority,Automated,isAutomatable,isNotAutomatable from automation_progress where platform = 'Cox' and update_date in (select MAX(update_date) FROM automation_progress) order by priority";

$data = array();

if ($result = mysqli_query( $db, $sql )){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
    }

   $newData = array();
   $firstLine = true;

   foreach ($data as $dataRow)
   {
        if($firstLine)
        {
           $newData[] =array_keys($dataRow);
           $firstLine = false;
        }
      $newData[] = array_values($dataRow);
   }

#return $newData;
echo json_encode($newData);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Here is the output from this script:

```
[["Priority","Automated","isAutomatable","isNotAutomatable"],["All","216","860","44"],["P1","213","567","34"],["P2","1","148","6"],["P3","2","136","3"],["P4","0","7","1"],["P5","0","2","0"]]
```

Finally I am making an ajax call to get the data from the script and load the data into a Google Chart.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

     function drawChart() {

       jQuery.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           dataType: "JSON",
           url: "http://10.21.124.252:8080/automationBarDataCox.php",
           success: function (jsonData) {
             var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

             var options = {
               chart: {
                 title: 'Automation Performance',
               },
               vAxes: {
                0: {title: 'Automated'},
              },
               legend: { position: 'left'},
               bars: 'vertical',
             };

             var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('cox_barchart'));

             chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
           }
       });

     }
  </script>
```

The data that is being returned is causing an issue when loading the chart as the numbers are coming back as strings and not numbers. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($newData);` and add the output into your question?...just before the `json_encode` instruction.

Comment: Do I see this correct? The data returned from the PHP script is not properly json-formatted. But you are expecting json data for your ajax call as defined by dataType: "JSON". Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp. You don't have any keys or colons but only values in the returned string.

Comment: intelligent type in `PDO` solution while `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES = false` and `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns an associative array of strings. If you want the values typed as integers you will have to do some extra work:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (count($data) === 0) {
            $data[] = array_keys($row);
        }

        $data[] = [
            $row['Priority'],
            intval($row['Automated']),
            intval($row['isAutomatable']),
            intval($row['isNotAutomatable']),
        ];
    }

    mysqli_close($db);

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

This also removes an unnecessary loop.